# Why I can't check target membership for GoogleService-Info.plist in react native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, info.plist

I was implementing push notification in react native for `ios` for that i was following [react native firebase document](https://rnfirebase.io/#3-ios-setup)

After adding GoogleService-info.plist I was getting this error:

```
could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project
```

When I check the Target Membership of GoogleService-Info.plist the project checking was disabled as shown in the below image

[image]

Here is, how I added file to the project:
1: Right click on project folder and selected option for add file to {project name}
after that I tried adding folder in both group and folder reference. But it showed same error [image]

Comment: Select info.plist, delete it and add again into the project. Don't create folder reference, Create groups.

Comment: Yeah I checked in both ways also..but same error

Comment: Have you tried after deleting derived data and re-run Xcode. Also check duplicates of same file.

Comment: I checked for the duplicates..and there is no duplicates on that